# Absolute URL wont work with fully static sites

Tags: html, css

Maybe a very newbie question.
I have a working site (apache, php, mysql etc) and links everywhere:

```
<img src="/images/x.gif" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js.css" />
```

in a CSS:

```
.x { background-image: url('/images/y.gif');
```

and it all works. But as soon as I put the generate content to a standalone HTML file, to another directory (so it can be viewed, without apache), links gets broken. I know I should loose the / character - but what about CSS? I must change them `.x { background-image: url('..images/y.gif');` ? I dont want to this relative tricking, I want absolute

Answer (score 1):

i use this

```
.x { background-image : url('../images/y.gif');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `'/` to `'./`

```
.x { background-image: url('./images/y.gif');
```

Comment: `.x { background-image: url('images/y.gif');`

Comment: but that CSS file is in /css directory, not where the .HTML is

Comment: You want absolute paths? Then use it: 'http://www.yoursite.com/images/image.png'. Or, maybe, i don't get your question...

Comment: but I dont have "yoursite.com" in this case, not even localhost. Im working on locally, with fully static content

Comment: `.x { background-image: url('../images/y.gif');` use it if both `css` folder and `image` folder are in same directory

Comment: thats OK, but cant I just leave the links as they are?